# Condition Formatting Checking only first 23 characters, need 25 checked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My conditional formatting statement is saying that these two numbers are identical:

```
9200025803572390001691385
9200025803572390001691393
```

when clearly the last two numbers are different. How can i adjust my conditional format to show only the true duplicates? Thanks

Comment: You will need to make them text strings and then check.  Excel is only accurate to 15 digits then it truncates the value with numbers.

Comment: Scott's suggestion is probably better than what I am going to suggest but I will anyway : why not "cut" the number in half and check each half : if both front halves and both rear halves are the same then ok, if one is different then not.

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing the number by 100000000000 then do the check. The number will not change only the crazy ending will be stored as a decimal.